# Python Pre-Define Function

Tags: python, numpy

In my code I use the following structure to avoid conditions in a for loop:

```
if patch_type == "zeros":
    patch_fct = np.zeros
elif patch_type == "ones":
    patch_fct = np.ones
elif patch_type == "rand":
    patch_fct = np.random.random_sample
else:
    raise "Error"

for k in range(10**9):
    m, n = comp_size()
    bla = patch_fct((m,n))
```

where `patch_fct` can be easily used with tupels.

Now I want to use the same approach to create a `patch_fct` that takes a tupel and returns uniformly distributed random numbers between -1 and 1. How can I do that?

I would like to do something like:

```
patch_fct = 2. * (np.random.random_sample - 0.5)
```

The approach from above does not seem to be the right one.

Comment: Could you show us your approach for the actual problem and how it does not work? Currently we only have your approach for a problem that you already seem to have solved.

Comment: By the way `raise "Error"` is a weird way to raise a `TypeError` and the error message will be "TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException".

Comment: ```2 * np.random.random_sample(10,10) - 1``` will probably do what you want.

Comment: @nick The size is not known before runtime.

Comment: @timgeb I added an example.

Comment: How about `def patch_fct(tup): return 2*(np.random.random_sample(tup) - 0.5)`?

Comment: Where does the input tuple get used in the output? Per your description, you don't seem to use it for anything at all.

Comment: `numpy.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=None)`?

Comment: @kabanus Great! I did not know that this function exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a function that does not already exist, you can just define it and use its name from now on.

For example:

```
if foo:
    def patch_fct(tup):
        return 2*(np.random.random_sample(tup) - 0.5)
elif bar:
    def patch_fct(tup):
        # do something else
else:
    patch_fct = another_existing_function
```

The chain of ifs and elses can be written a bit more smoothly with the help of a dictionary.

For your original code, you could write

```
patch_functions = {'zeros': np.zeros, 
                   'ones': np.ones, 
                   'rand': np.random.random_sample}
```

and then use it like this:

```
>>> patch_functions['zeros'](5)
>>> array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

This will automatically throw a `KeyError` if you are trying to access a key that does not exist in the dictionary.

You can also put self-defined functions inside a dictionary, either by defining them prior to insertion or using anonymous `lambda` functions. Demo:

```
>>> def fun1(tup):
...:    return sum(tup) + 1
>>> 
>>> my_functions = {'my_sum': fun1, 'my_random': lambda tup: 2*(np.random.random_sample(tup) - 0.5)}
>>> my_functions['my_sum']((2, 5))
>>> 8
>>> my_functions['my_random']((2, 5))
>>> 
array([[-0.20203832, -0.23868021,  0.72052191,  0.72931098, -0.57160796],
       [-0.45117601, -0.95461634, -0.52232593, -0.24011216, -0.83875935]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` provides such a [function explicitly](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
numpy.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=None)
```

`size` is the amount of times to draw - this can be a tuple stating the dimensions of the resulting array. `size=(10,10)` will yield a 10x10 matrix.

If I understand you correctly then:

```
def patch_fct(size):
    return numpy.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=size)
```

and `size` can be a tuple (or not).

In general searching `numpy` with some math/probability thing will yield the correct answer on the first hit.

Comment: I still wonder how to use this function as I used the other functions in my question? `patch_fct=np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=None); print(patch_fct(10,10))` does not work.

Comment: @Samuel what is `patch_fct` supposed to do? your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to avoid conditions in my code. Therefore I want to be able to use `patch_fct((m,n))` instead of `np.zero` or `np.ones` etc.

Comment: @Samuel You still did not say what is `patch_fct(m,n)` supposed to do. Does it return an mxn array with numbers drawn from the uniform distribution? if so see my edit. Does it return an mxn array with the same number, which is randomly selected? please be specific.

Comment: It returns an `mxn` array with numbers drawn from the uniform distribution. Problem solved!

Comment: @Samuel so that is exactly the function from `numpy` - just use a tuple with the `size` parameter.